# Drawing an image using its full size rather than asking me for its dimensions in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am loading an external image with JavaFX:

```
Image tile = new Image(imageFile.toURI().toURL().toString(),width, height, true,true);
```

You need to supply the width and height. How can I get the image's width and height?

Now, I *know* that the width and height of a PNG image are determined by the bytes from 12 to 20 or something like that, so technically you could open a byte stream and interpret the bytes. However, this seems overkill for the  simple task of drawing an image in my JavaFX application. Is there not a way to draw an image with its full size without asking me to supply the dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the Image using a constructor which does not include dimensions (e.g. [new Image(url)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-)):

```
Image image = new Image(url);
```